# How can I write a simple cadence with lilyglyphs?

Tags: music, lilypond

I want to write a simple cadence with lilyglyphs with a Cadential Six-Four chord. How do i do it? Here is a picture of the needed result:[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}


\begin{document}

I-IV-V(64-->53)-I-cadence


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, provide some picture of needed result please

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh I've tried to depict the needed result (See edit in post).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what I've done, but it looks very similar to Your screenshot, hope it will help You...

*Also, I have tried to make "functions" to make coding easier, but it doesn't work properly (I don't know why, if somebody knows, correct my code please)*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\newcommand{\qq}[2]{$\substack{#1\\#2} $}
%\newcommand{\qqq}[2]{$\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2} $}
%\newcommand{\q}[2]{$\begin{array}{c} 6-4\\4-3\\ \end{array}$}

\begin{document}
$I-IV-V^{\substack{6-4\\4-3}}-I-cadence$ \\

$I-IV-V^{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{6-4}{4-3}}-I-cadence$ \\

$I-IV-V^{\begin{array}{c}6-4\\4-3\\ \end{array}}-I-cadence$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look if I find other solutions, but yours is a good solution for the time being.